# Java Streams - Change field of an element

Tags: java, arrays, list, java-8, java-stream

I've been googling for a while, but I couldn't find the answer I am looking for.

I have a **stream** of products, and each one of those contains these fields:

```
private String ID;
private float price;
private int quantity;
```

I need to change the *quantity* field of a specific product without consuming the rest of the stream. Is it possible?

How can I search for this element (by product *ID*) and then change the value of *quantity* field?

I was thinking I could use `.peek()`, but I couldn't figure out how to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you have a setter method for the quantity, you can use `peek` to change the value.  Test for the product ID you want, then call the setter, all in a lambda expression (a `Consumer`).

```
stream.peek( p -> {
    if ("YourID".equals(p.getID()))
    {
         p.setQuantity(newQuantity);
    }
});
```

Comment: Is it safe to modify a peek element? Aren't peek elements presumably read-only and thread-safe?